# Jenkins & CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, git, jenkins, cocoapods

I'm currently experimenting with Jenkins and CocoaPods. I've read that adding the CocoaPods and Xcode plugins to Jenkins would suffice to get a Jenkins build. Seems like I've missed something and I just can't figure it out.

The Xcode Workspace is configured to have a derived data folder relative to the workspace and that folder is build.
The main project's schema file in the workspace is shared.
And all this is pushed to a repository: https://github.com/cyupa/JenkinsWithCocoaPods.git

I still end up with the same console output, that it wasn't able to find the Pods library build:

```
library not found for -lPods clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:    
Ld build/JenkinsWithCocoaPods.build/Release-iphoneos/JenkinsWithCocoaPods.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/JenkinsWithCocoaPods normal armv7s    
Ld build/JenkinsWithCocoaPods.build/Release-iphoneos/JenkinsWithCocoaPods.build/Objects-normal/armv7/JenkinsWithCocoaPods normal armv7  
Ld build/JenkinsWithCocoaPods.build/Release-iphoneos/JenkinsWithCocoaPods.build/Objects-normal/arm64/JenkinsWithCocoaPods normal arm64 (3 failures) Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure 
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong? Should I run some scripts, isn't `xcodebuild` already integrating the Pods build while building the target?

Comment: Any luck ? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Hi, Redwarp, see my answer below, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a while, I managed to get it right. Because CocoaPods adds more Build Schemes, you must specify the scheme you want to use. In this case the main scheme associated with the main target.
I also compiled a step-by-step tutorial on how to setup Jenkins for your iOS project here: https://github.com/cyupa/JenkinsCI-iOS